# Oracle SQL Developer custom format settings

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using an Oracle SQL Developer and it's built in code formatting settings are far away from being fine.

there is an option to setup a custom format, instead of using external tools like notepad++ with it's plugins, but I get lost in the code.

So I have 2 questions:

1. where can I get tutorial about code formatting customization?
2. Can someone share an enhanced format configuration file?

Answer (score -1):

There are good tutorials on Pluralsight about code formatting in SQL developer.

Comment: thanks, Iv'e watched the tutorial [link](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?name=sql-developer-getting-productive-m3&mode=live&clip=6&course=sql-developer-getting-productive&author=pankaj-jain), the formatting section. but it's very basic, and doesn't meet the needs and question.